# Sticky div scrolls too far

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a jquery code which makes an existing element follow the scroll of the user. I want it to stop when reaching a certain element `#header-line`, but it's not consistent. On some PDPs it scrolls and stops there, on others, it scrolls past the line.

Page: https://www.norli.no/to-pappaer
(Code is not activated here)

jQuery

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {

(function($) {
    var element = $('.product-add-form'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;

    var hr = $('#header-line > hr');
        topOfLine = hr.offset().top;

    var topMargin = 250;

    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var nextPosition = scrollTop - originalY + topMargin;
        var maxPositionAllowed = topOfLine - 1000;

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
          top: scrollTop + 250 < originalY ? 0 : Math.min(nextPosition, maxPositionAllowed )
        }, 0);
    });
})(jQuery);
  });
});
```

Comment: You could just use CSS' [Position Sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) `position: sticky; top: 250px;` or similar without the need of jQuery

Comment: I tried that at first but it didn't work. But as Brandon mentioned below I had to change the overflow to visible on a containing div. But thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely take advantage of using `position: sticky` if you are able to make sure all parent elements of the sticky element have `overflow: visible`

In that link you posted, if you wanted `.product-add-form` to be `position: sticky` you would have to make sure `.off-canvas-wrapper` has the `overflow: hidden` changed to `overflow: visible`.

I made an example fiddle of that page you shared so you could see how easy it would be to make that side form sticky.

https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/d30phae8/8/

Comment: That's excellent! Is there any way to make the price above also follow the scroll but stay relative to the box underneath? I tried using the container for those 2 divs, but it's longer than it's content,which makes it stop scrolling earlier than intended.

Comment: Never mind, it works! Thanks a lot. I tried position:sticky before all this, but I didn't know I had to change the overflow of that other class. Learn something new every day, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, check my updated fiddle out. https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/d30phae8/12/